# Update Textbox if var changes

Tags: powershell

I want to update my WPF PowerShell GUI. I set up a small GUI with one button and one textbox to test my script. It looks like:

```
[void][System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName('presentationframework')
Add-Type -AssemblyName System.Windows.Forms

[xml]$XAML = @"
<Window
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        Title="test" Height="630" Width="500" ResizeMode="NoResize" WindowStartupLocation="CenterScreen">
    <Grid>
        <StackPanel>
            <Button Name="test" Content="Button" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="75"/>
            <TextBox Name="write" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="23" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="TextBox" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="120"/>
        </StackPanel>
    </Grid>
</Window>
"@

$reader = (New-Object System.Xml.XmlNodeReader $xaml)
try {
    $Form = [Windows.Markup.XamlReader]::Load($reader)
} catch {
    Write-Host "Something is wrong"; exit
}

$xaml.SelectNodes("//*[@Name]") | %{
    Set-Variable -Name ($_.Name) -Value $Form.FindName($_.Name)
}

$test.Add_Click({
    Write-Host $varvar
    Start-Process powershell -Argument ".\varchecker.ps1"
})

$Form.ShowDialog() | Out-Null
```

By clicking the button I start another script where I read a variable. This looks like:

```
while ($true) {
    $global:varvar = Get-Content var.txt
    Write-Host $varvar
}
```

Now I want to print the var from the started script to the textbox in the other script. Is this possible? Or the better question: is that a good way to do that?

Comment: No i didnt solve the problem, but i have done a workaround so i dont need the "live" update of the GUI.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you can do it this way. You are trying to start a new PowerShell process, getting some data and passing it to the parent process. I think you can sort of do it in C with `pipe()` and `fork()` but havent found a way to do it in PowerShell yet.

You can however, use `Start-Job`, which creates a process in the background. Alternatively, you can look at `Runspaces` too for multithreading.

You can also use `Invoke-Expression` to call the script.
All you have to do from the script is return `$Varvar`.

If you can tell us what problem you are trying to solve with this method, maybe folks can be more helpful.

Comment: I'm getting a datastream every 200 ms from a microcontroller. I want to print this datastream in my GUI without freezing the GUI.

Comment: Powershell maybe ill equipped to do that. However, it sounds like what you need is a listener program that can collect and then queue the data stream so you can then display that on ur GUI. Technically, you can create a service to listen. the problem would be to transfer it to the GUI process. A queuing program could help do that and then let the PowerShell GUI query and clear the queue. Simplest form, a text file would do but thats a lot of IO operations. Alternatively, a database. hardest part would be writing the listener service.

Answer (score 0):

Getting values from a new PowerShell process inside your GUI is much too complicated if all you want is to read the contents of a file.

Why not do it all from the GUI code you have?

```
# [System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName is deprecated.
Add-Type -AssemblyName PresentationFramework

[xml]$xaml = @"
<Window
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        Title="test" Height="630" Width="500" ResizeMode="NoResize" WindowStartupLocation="CenterScreen">
    <Grid>
        <StackPanel>
            <Button Name="test" Content="Button" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="75"/>
            <TextBox Name="write" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="23" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="TextBox" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="120"/>
        </StackPanel>
    </Grid>
</Window>
"@

$reader = New-Object System.Xml.XmlNodeReader $xaml
try {
    $Form = [Windows.Markup.XamlReader]::Load($reader)
} 
catch {
    Write-Host "Something is wrong"; exit
}

# get references for the button and textbox objects into PowerShell variables.
$button  = $Form.FindName("test")
$textBox = $Form.FindName("write")

$button.Add_Click({
    # don't start a new PowerShell process, but simply read the file here
    $textBox.Text = $var = Get-Content -Path 'PATH TO var.txt' -Raw
    Write-Host $var
})

$Form.ShowDialog() | Out-Null

# clean-up
$reader.Dispose()
```